# Structural Optimization

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling, applications

Currently, I am working on a problem in which I need to use **MILP** to model equilibrium equations in a lightweight structure. Although this is an application based question, I wondered if there is a good reference in the literature discussing the mathematical modeling of such an application based on statical concepts.

A brief discussion of structural optimization is given in chapter 15 of **Linear Programming: Foundations and Extensions**, by *Robert J. Vanderbei*.

Structural optimization is the general name that researchers use for a wide range of research topics in the literature, i.e., Shape optimization, Size optimization and also Topology optimization.

Comment: "use MILP to model equilibrium equations" Are those complementarity conditions?

Comment: Actually, there are two different approaches to model this kind of problems. I use the plastic form in which the forces in each joint should be in equilibrium and also the moments if the joints are welded. Those conditions are not complementarity conditions.

Comment: Given the   emphasis on engineering modeling, you might have better luck at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ which also has a lot of optimization stuff.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks for the great suggestion, I haven’t asked my question there yet but I believe I will find good answers for my structural questions there. As you mentioned there are lots of questions covering both optimization and mechanical concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at the work of Mathias Stolpe. He has done a lot of modelling for structural optimization problems with integer constraints. See for example his [PhD thesis](https://orbit.dtu.dk/en/publications/models-and-methods-for-structural-topology-optimization-with-discrete-design-variables(eefb877e-065f-43a0-9958-d42eef42c2da).html). As you already written, the topic comes from a more continuous direction. See the [nice book by Martin Bendsoe and Ole Sigmund](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540429920) for a really good overview. You can also have a look at the [website](http://www.topopt.mek.dtu.dk/) of this chair.

If you provide more information on your problem I can adjust my answer to guide you to more relevant papers.